# String Concatenation with comma

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to build the string with comma but I get extra space. How can I remove extra space between zipcode and country_name? Here is my string. Thank you for any suggestion.

```
SELECT
    (COALESCE(address + ', ', '') +
    COALESCE(city + ', ', '') +
    COALESCE(state_code + ' ', '') +
    COALESCE(zipcode + ' ', '') +
    COALESCE(country_name + '', '')) address
from table1
where a_id = 2
```

Here is the result:

```
tewt, test ct, DE 4444                 United States
```

Comment: What is the datatype of ZipCode?

Comment: zipcode datatype is varchar(20)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the RTRIM function which remove white space from right side of the variable. Check also LTRIM for the left cases.

Answer (score 0):

I would change table column datatape to varchar(x) from char(x) or to nvarchar(x) from nchar(x). And change the data so they dont contain spaces. Just have to do that once and make changes so that app is not storing white spaces anymore.

char(x) and nchar(x) i would use just when there is fixed length strings, but this does not seem to be the case.